# How to set a minimal logging level with loguru?

Tags: python, loguru

I would like to use a different logging level in development and production. To do so, I need early in my program to set the minimal level for logs to be triggered. The default is to output all severities:

```py
from loguru import logger as log

log.debug("a debug log")
log.error("an error log")

# output
# 2022-09-15 16:51:23.325 | DEBUG    | __main__:<module>:3 - a debug log
# 2022-09-15 16:51:23.327 | ERROR    | __main__:<module>:4 - an error log
```

There is a [*Changing the level of an existing handler*](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/resources/recipes.html#changing-the-level-of-an-existing-handler) section in the documentation, that states among others that

> Once a handler has been added, it is actually not possible to update
> it. (...)
>
> The most straightforward workaround is to `remove()` your handler and
> then re-`add()` it with the updated level parameter.

My problem is that I have not added anything, so there is nothing to remove. I also cannot modify `log`. So what should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like so:

```py
import sys
from loguru import logger as log
log.remove() #remove the old handler. Else, the old one will work along with the new one you've added below'
log.add(sys.stdout, level="INFO") 
log.debug("debug message")
log.info("info message")
log.warning("warning message")
log.error("error message")
```

You can use `sys.stdout` or other file object, in place of `sys.stdout`.
[More info in this related GitHub thread](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru/issues/51).